# Unity - AndroidJavaObject.Call from another thread

Tags: java, c#, android, multithreading, unity-game-engine

Right now I am making an application that sends messages from Unity to a bluetooth low energy device using an Android Java plugin in between. Things like scanning connecting and sending messages works fine from the Unity main thread. However I wanted to see if I could make sending messages from a separate thread work as I do send around 10-20 and wait for acknowledges after each one to send the next one.

I know Unity isn't thread safe so calling certain functions from the thread is problematic but does that include the Android Java Object class ? Note that this is just a simple example so you can hopefully understand what I am trying to do. This works without issue from the main thread.

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            androidJavaObject.Call("MethodName", message);
        }
        }).Start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use it on background thread. You can't use UnityEngine.Object derived classes. AndroidJavaObject doesn't inherit from it. You can also think about creating threads inside the native plugin you have. So inside Unity you can only trigger methods that will create new thread in java class or reuse some existing one or whatever.